# How can I get safari Bookmarks on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

I'm now developing new app that needs to show mobileSafari Bookmarks list ...

I want to use common API,but there seems no apis...

I saw following URL and  copy code to my app..

http://www.telesphoreo.org/pipermail/iphone-gcc/2009-February/000632.html

But,it doesn't show any of bookmarks list..

Any idea?

Please help me...

Thanks and regards...

Answer (score 2):

Mobile Safari bookmarks are not accessible via the iOS SDK currently. Even if your example code worked, it would most likely be rejected by Apple. Sorry.

Comment: Just to add on to this point, that sample code will only work on jailbroken devices. The code accesses the bookmarks plist file which is outside of an app store app's sandboxed environment.